# jQuery: Manipulate the previous div (not parent or child)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a page where I have to make changes to a system generated div that occurs many times on a page and does not have a unique identifier, however the div that always occurs after it does have a unique class identifier.

So what I am trying to do is access the previous div through the target div (in this case **content**)

In an attempt to be clear, what I need to do is target the **content** div but append a child to the div called **bg-layer**.

The code I have at the moment is here ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XHA4/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bg-layer"></div>
<div class="content">hello world</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('???').append('<div class="inserted">I am the inserted div</div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the content div with [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) then use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling element

```
jQuery('.content').prev().append('<div class="inserted">I am the inserted div</div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DSaDy/)

Comment: Hey Arun, you guys are both thinking the same :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you wanna do is

```
jQuery('.content').prev().append('<div class="inserted">I am the inserted div</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZZxf/

Comment: Hey thanks for the working answer, I'm giving this to Arun  just because he came in first with the identical (from what I can see) answer.

Comment: Why did you post the exact same answer as Arun, who posted *~10 min* before you? Do you think a duplicate answer provides any additional value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
jQuery('.content').siblings('.bg-layer').append('<div class="inserted">I am the inserted div</div>');
```

This will target your `.bg-layer` anywhere as long as `.bg-layer` is the sibling of your `.content` div

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XHA4/1/)**

Comment: Cool, never heard of siblings before!